# How to load all images from folder? (Processing, Java)

Tags: java, image, processing, loadimage

please help me. I want to load multiple images into this processing sketch without knowing the datanames. So that i can always just put `.png` images into the data folder and the program automatically loads them in. I've searched in some forums but didn't find anything except some code that I've already used but it doesn't run properly.

As soon as the program starts **it gives me a `NullPointerException` at `image();`**

This is the consoleoutput:

```
4096
D:\Program Files\processing-3.3.7\PROJECTS\Blendertutorial\data
[0] "1.png"
[1] "2.png"
[2] "3.png"
[3] "4.png"
[4] "5.png"
[5] "6.png"
[6] "7.png"
```

Also **why is the `folder.list();` output such a huge number? I only have 7 images in there...**

```
import java.io.File;
String fileExtension = ".png";

java.io.File folder = new java.io.File(sketchPath("/PROJECTS/Blendertutorial/data"));
java.io.FilenameFilter extfilter = new java.io.FilenameFilter() {
  boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(fileExtension);
  }
};

PImage images;
String[] imageNames;
int i=0;
long folderInhalt = folder.length();

void setup(){
  size(500,500);
  println(folder.length());
  println(folder);
  printArray(imageNames);

  imageNames = folder.list(extfilter);
}

void draw(){
  if(mousePressed){
    images = loadImage(folder+"/"+imageNames[0]);
    println(images);
    println(imageNames[i]);
    delay(200);
    i++;
  }
  image(images,0,0);      //NULL POINTER EXCEPTION!
}
```

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but you should not load images inside the `draw()` function like that. Load them from the `setup()` function instead. Otherwise you'll load an image 60 times per second, which will cause your computer to catch on fire.

Comment: Thanks. I only did it in this example because im calling delay() and because i dont want it to "preload" bu load when its needed.

Comment: The problem is that the mouse will be pressed for more than one frame, so you're constantly reloading the image. At the very least you should cache your images so you don't reload them more than once, but most likely you should just load them all during setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens in your code when draw() is called, but `mousePressed` is false?

Consider your code:

```
PImage images;
...
...
...

void draw(){
  if(mousePressed){
    images = loadImage(folder+"/"+imageNames[0]);
    println(images);
    println(imageNames[i]);
    delay(200);
    i++;
  }
  image(images,0,0);      //NULL POINTER EXCEPTION!
}
```

You have declared `images` but have not instantiated it.

In the case of `mousePressed==false`, `images` will remain null.

This behavior can explain your `NullPointerException` - you are invoking the `image` method with a null valued parameter.

Answer (score 1):

> why is the folder.list(); output such a huge number? I only have 7 images in there...

You aren't calling `folder.list()`. You're calling `folder.length()`. This function returns the size of the file, which is undefined for folders. More info can be found in [the Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length()).

Also, this is not directly related to your problem, but you should not load images inside the `draw()` function like that. Load them from the `setup()` function instead. Otherwise you'll load an image 60 times per second, which will cause your computer to catch on fire.

Moving your loading to `setup()` will also fix your `NullPointerException` problem, because you'll no longer be drawing null images when the mouse is not pressed.

Comment: hey, but i can only put the loading into setup(), the rest still has to go into  draw() because i want it to update on mouseclick

Comment: @OliverTworkowski That's fine. You should put your loading into `setup()` and the mouse clicking code inside `draw()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void readImagesPath(String dir){
   File folder = new File(dir);
   File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (File file : listOfFiles) {
      if (file.isFile()) {
         System.out.println(file.getName());
      }
    }
 }
```

With this code you can retrive the image paths and then you can load and draw them.

Answer (score 0):

I have this and it seems to work (based on the file selection example)

```
void fileSelected(File selection) {
if (selection == null) {
println("Window was closed or the user hit cancel.");
} else {
println("User selected " + selection.getAbsolutePath());
img = loadImage(selection.getAbsolutePath());
}
}
```